# Fire a comboBox SelectedIndexChanged event programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, events, combobox, selectedindex, selectedindexchanged

There is a comboBox and a button on a win form. How can I fire the comboBox selectedIndexChanged by clicking on the button.

Comment: You could call the event handler method directly.  Though it doesn't make a lot of sense to do this, why do you want to fire an event that didn't actually happen?

Comment: The combobox can have only 1 index (it is a 1-D control and anything beyond that wouldn't make any sense). If you want to create a given functionality and to somehow involve a combobox (the actions which are performed when a new index is selected), you might come up with something. Please, explain clearly what you want (and accept that a comboxbox will always have just 1 index).

Comment: @David This combo-box load a file. This file is changing frequently. So by calling this event I can load the new file. Can you please write an example.

Comment: @UserMat: Is this file being loaded from code?  Can't you just call the code which does this, instead of trying to "trick" the UI into thinking an event has taken place?

Comment: @varocarbas This combo-box doesn't have 1 index for always. It can have 1 or more than 1 indexes. It depends to the number of files in a directory that have to be loaded.

Comment: I am completely sure that your combox (like any other combobox) can only deal with one single index. As said, try to put your ideas together and describe clearly what you want to accomplish (e.g., "the user does this, what provokes that; and then the app reads this file and...") and we might advise you how to get it.

Comment: @David Yes it is. No I can't. I only need to fire comboBox changedIndex event programically without changing the index.

Comment: @UserMat: That doesn't make any sense... If the file is loaded from code, and you're currently in the context of code, then you *can* call the code which loads the file if that's what you're trying to do.  You're very much over-complicating things.  Calling a method is far simpler and more straightforward than trying to falsely trigger a UI event.  Just call the code you need to call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should rethink your code design a little. It seems you want to raise the event to trigger some action indirectly. Why not try it like this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // do the things that should happen only if a real change happend
     // ...
     // then do the special thing you want
     DoTheOtherStuff();
}
private void button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do the things to happen when the button is clicked
    // ...
    // then do the special thing you want
    DoTheOtherStuff();
}
private void DoTheOtherStuff()
{
    // the special thing you want
}
```

EDIT: If your legacy code is so awkward as your comment suggests, you can still use this awkward way:

```
private void button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(comboBox1, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```